# Openscad: Getting error message from open bracket; Why cannot I reassign an array variable?

Tags: openscad

Why am I getting an error message from the open brackets in the if statement? How can I reassign the vector variables if not like this?

```
array = [[14,2],[60,3],[1,43]];
echo (array);


for (x = [1:len(array)])
{
    a = array[x-1][1];
    b = array[x][1];

    if (b>a)
    {
        array[x-1][1] = b;
        array[x][1] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of "error message"? Why did you tag your question "openscad"? What language do you use, python?

Comment: I'm doing this in openscad, a program for creating 3d images. It has it's own language. I need to sort an array so the image will be created correctly.

Comment: Oh and the error message is literally ERROR: Parser error in line 14: syntax error 
ERROR: Compilation failed!

Comment: It's not possible to reassign variables or values in arrays/lists.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any way to sort arrays of arrays in openscad?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to a list, array or even variable. You can only create new ones.

The user manual has an example implementation for you:

[Sorting a vector](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/List_Comprehensions#Sorting_a_vector)